# How to make a sum of all Values from an List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a List which looks like this:

`values = {
'123456':['Value1':41235534],
'543123':['Value1':12958362],
'34573':['Value1':1295937]}`

And when I try to make a sum like this:

```
sum1 = sum(int(i['Value1']) for i in values)
```

I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable".
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Syntax error. Post real code please.

Comment: that is a dictionary, not a list

Answer (score 2):

The structure you posted is not valid Python. Instead, it must be declared like so:

```
values = {
  '123456':{'Value1':41235534},
  '543123':{'Value1':12958362},
  '34573':{'Value1':1295937}}

sum1 = sum(b['Value1'] for a, b in values.items())
```

Comment: you could have made more short and pythonic this way sum(b['Value1'] for  b in values.values())

Answer (score 0):

As-is, `values` is invalid syntax. To fix:

```
values = {'123456':{'Value1':41235534},'543123':{'Value1':12958362},'34573':{'Value1':1295937}}

sum(j['Value1'] for i,j in values.items())
```